# Are there any jEdit syntax highlighting modes for Objective-J

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting, cappuccino, jedit, objective-j

I have found some in the Cappuccino website (vim, textmate and SubEthaEdit), but not for jEdit, and unfortunately I'm just starting on Objective-J so can't make my own. If anyone has got one of them lying around it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the JEdit [features page](http://jedit.org/index.php?page=features) it already supports Objective C.

Comment: It has for a while too, back when I was doing pop11 it already had Objective-C, but, is Objective-J similar enough that I can use that?

Answer (score 0):

One of my favorite things about JEdit is how easy it is to define a new syntax highlighting mode.  I work in a land in which every fool wants to create his own custom configuration file language and I've gotten to where I can create a new approximate syntax highlighting mode in about 5 minutes.  I start by copying a mode that is similar to the new language I wanted to create and then iteratively refining the edit mode as I learn more parts of the language. I did this with Specman ( a hardware verification language ) as I was going through the intro course.